# React when button was clicked return many other buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react. I want to write a single game with reactjs. I have a problem. When click the button, i call the function `priest` and return 4 more buttons, but they are not seemed.My function is

```
 usePriest = (evt) => {
            return(
              <div>
              <button className="button_player1">heyo</button>
              <button className= "button_player2">heyo</button>
              <button className= "button_player3">heyo</button>
              <button className = "button_player4">heyo</button>
              </div>
              )
          }
```

And i call it inside here

```
    else if (mycards0==="/static/media/priest.ae71698d.jpg") {
          return ( 
<div>
            <button className="button_card1_use" onClick={(evt) => this.usePriest(evt)}>Use</button>
            <button className="button_card1_discard">Discard</button>
            <div className="about1"><p>Priest</p>
            Player is allowed to see another player's hand.     
           </div>
</div>
```

How can i return 4 buttons when `use` was clicked?

Comment: You are doing right, you just have to follow a tweak, please follow this link- [Show/Hide DOM](https://www.nicesnippets.com/blog/how-to-hide-and-show-div-in-react-js), it will work like charm. Happy Coding ;-)

Comment: This isn't quite how renderable JSX is rendered, you need to either save the computed to state (to be rendered later in `render`), or more simply save some state value to toggle the rendering of the four extra buttons. This is a process called [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, declare a state

```
const [showButton, setShowButton] = useState(false);
```

then in your code use this markup

```html
<div>
    {showButton && (
      <div>
        <button className="button_player1">heyo</button>
        <button className="button_player2">heyo</button>
        <button className="button_player3">heyo</button>
        <button className="button_player4">heyo</button>
      </div>
    )}
    <button className="button_card1_use" onClick={evt => usePriest(evt)}>
      Use
    </button>
    <button className="button_card1_discard">Discard</button>
    <div className="about1">
      <p>Priest</p>
      Player is allowed to see another player's hand.
    </div>
</div>
```

now in your `usePriest` function do this

```js
const usePriest = evt => {
    setShowButton(true);
  };
```

So whenever the `showButton` will be `true` those three buttons will show up

Comment: It gives parsing error in here
```const usePriest = evt => {```

Comment: You are using a class-based component can you share the full code somehow. I have given in function-based procedure

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tsbd0oe5
Could you have a look if you have a time?

Comment: sure give me some time

Comment: just remove the const from the beginning as because it is a class-based component it doesn't require it. usePriest = evt => {
    var { ShowButton } = this.state;
    showButton=true;
    this.setState(showButton);}

Comment: ```usePriest = evt => { var { showButton } = this.state;  this.state.showButton=true; this.setState(showButton);}```
```state = {
            showButton:false,
            setShowButton:false}```
 and 
      <button className="button_card1_use" onClick={evt => this.usePriest(evt)}>
        
However when i click the button, it shows setState(...): takes an object of state variables to update or a function which returns an object of state variables.

Comment: you messed up all the thing everything was fine in the function before just remove ```const``` and where you have written {showButton && ............} there write ```this.state.showButton```

Comment: So when i clicked one of them can i make them false and they will disapper?

Comment: Don't forget to give an upvote so that other's also get helped by it

Comment: I can not give it, reputation is too low